# Valum's File Uploader?

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

Has anyone here used Valum's file uploader script?   Is it secure and cross - browser (including older versions) compatible for you too recommend it?  It does say that it supports recent versions of FF, Chrome and IE.... just askig for a second opinion ..any known issues etc. ?

Also, I am just testing it out but the file upload fails. It does about 60 - 70% and then fails.

Just tried some troubleshooting  - Server permissions are ok, so is file size settings both on php.ini and in the script, i set debug to true (as mentioned for troubleshooting) and then tried uploading again but i don't see any message.

I am testing this on FF 3.6.24 and Chrome 15.0.874.121

Maybe someone can throw some more light on how good this is and perhaps help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried some different file types or sizes? Maybe the max upload filesize value in PHP is too low.

Comment: all file's i tried were under Max_File_Size setting in php.ini  . Max_file_size is set to 64 M.... that's a lot.... my files are all about 20 kb and under.....

Comment: Why's the question being downvoted... I just need some help and recommendation on this....

Comment: What exactly happens when the upload fails?

Comment: well nothing much ... it just shows the progress bar ... about 67% complete and then the message - failed.   Also, verified the upload directory ... just in case it did upload but was displaying a fake message ... however nothing like this.. nothing gets uploaded.

Comment: Hm sorry I don't know this valums file uploader.. But you could try to create an upload form and script with HTML and php or get some code from the web.

Comment: Try adjusting `post_max_size`, `max_input_time`， and `memory_limit` in your `php.ini`. Also try adding `set_time_limit(0);`, so that the script does not timeout.

Comment: @phpdev - post_max_size - 64M , max_input_time -60 , memory_limit - 128M .... however i don't find any settings for set_time_limit ... there's nothing like this variable in quick php.ini config on shared hosting.

Comment: @DRP96 thanks anyway, this one has multiple file uploads, progress bar etc.  so i thought this was better than a simple file upload script....

Comment: @user481913, your settings looks fine. Perhaps set `max_input_time` to `1200`. You need to put `set_time_limit(0);` in the uploader script. It's a function call. :)

Comment: @phpdev - i can't edit max_input_time   ... ill need to ask the host to do so....  Do you mean setTimeout(function())  instead of  set_time_limit ()?  There isn't any function with thatname in the script.. i tried setting that to 0 instead of 1 ...i'm not sure if 0 is better than 1 :) It didn't work

Comment: @user481913: setTimeout is probably a functon by the developer of the script. I am talking about this one: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php Setting it to 0 means no timeout. Setting it to 1 means timeout in 1 second and so on. But in anycase, I don't think this is the cause of your problem :( Can you confirm that your internet isn't dropping out while uploading? How about trying to upload a file to a filehost?

Comment: +1 for helping out trying some  basic common sense checks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed .... was missing some module/libraries that needed to be included which i was under the impression were already there.

Thnaks all  for helping out.